# Calculate expected value $\mathbb{E}[(\frac{X}{n}-p)^2$] with $X$ is binomial $(n,p)$

Tags: probability-theory, expectation, binomial-distribution

I have to calculate the expected value $\mathbb{E}[(\frac{X}{n}-p)^2] = \frac{pq}{n}$, but everytime i try to solve it my answer is $\frac{p}{n} - p^2$, which is wrong.

What i did:
Let X be binomial distributed.

$ \mathbb{E}[(\frac{X}{n}-p)^2]
=\mathbb{E}[(\frac{X}{n})^2-2(\frac{X} {n}p)+p^2]
\\ =\mathbb{E}[(\frac{X}{n})^2]+(-2)\mathbb{E}[\frac{X}{n}p]+(\mathbb{E}[X])^2 \\ = \mathbb{E}[(\frac{X}{n})^2] - 2p\mathbb{E}[\frac{X}{n}]+p^2 \\= \mathbb{E}[(\frac{X}{n})^2] - 2p\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}[X]+p^2\\= 
\mathbb{E}[(\frac{X}{n})^2] - 2p\frac{1}{n}np+p^2 \\= \mathbb{E}[(\frac{X}{n})^2] - p^2 \\ = \frac{p}{n}-p^2$

Comment: Sorry but, at the last line of your proof, where is the step $$\mathbb E\left[\left(\frac Xn\right)^2\right] = \frac pn$$ coming from? This is plainly false...

Comment: I thought, $\mathbb{E}[(\frac{X}{n})^2] = n(\frac{1}{n^2}\mathbb{P}(X=1)+\mathbb{P}(X=0)\frac{0}{n^2}$, but this is only for $\mathbb{E}[X])$

Comment: No, no, the formula $$E(X^2)=\sum_xx^2P(X=x)$$ is perfectly correct for every discrete random variable $X$ and your $X$ is indeed discrete. But the (huge) trouble is that the values your $X$ takes are definitely not only $0$ or $1$... Please reread what the words `binomial distribution` mean.

Comment: i assumed that $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[Z_{1}]+..+\mathbb{E}[Z_{n}]$ with $X=(Z_{1},...,Z_{n})$ and every $\mathbb{E}[Z_{1}]$ is a single trail which means $n=1$

Comment: FYI, the assertion "[X]=[Z1]+..+[Zn] with X=(Z1,...,Zn)" is simply **absurd**. Can you see why?

Comment: I dont know, i tried to use what is written in our script.

Comment: This ("[X]=[Z1]+..+[Zn] with X=(Z1,...,Zn)") is written in your script? Sorry but I highly doubt that.

Comment: It says "What is the best way to calculate $\mathbb{E}$? Mostly by writing X as sum: X=Z1+..+Zn E[X]=E[X1]+...+E[Xn]", whoops you got me.

Comment: Please compare `X=Z1+...+Zn` and `X=(Z1,...,Zn)`.

Comment: $X=(z1,..,zn)$ is a tuple which is drawn out of a set $S=\{1,..,n\}^n$ and $X=Z1+..+Zn$ means our drawn value is the sum of n draws out of $S=\{1,..,n\}^n$.

Comment: Dunno whom you are talking to... Anyway, since it seems needed to belabor the obvious here, let us recall once and for all that $$Z_1+\cdots+Z_n\ne(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your derivation until you arrived at this equality: $$\mathbb{E}[\Big(\frac{X}{n}-p\Big)^2]=\ldots=\mathbb{E}[\Big(\frac{X}{n}\Big)^2]-p^2=\frac{1}{n^2}\mathbb{E}[X^2]-p^2$$ Now insert $$\mathbb{E}[X^2]=\mathrm{Var}[X]+(\mathbb{E}[X])^2=np(1-p)+(np)^2\tag{$\ast$}$$
to obtain
$$\mathbb{E}[\Big(\frac{X}{n}-p\Big)^2]=\frac{p(1-p)}{n}=\frac{pq}{n}$$
**Edit:** If you don't know the formula given in $(\ast)$, then you have to calculate
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[X^2]&=\sum_{k=0}^n k^2P(X=k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n [k(k-1)+k]P(X=k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n k(k-1)P(X=k)+\sum_{k=1}^n kP(X=k)\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^n k(k-1)P(X=k)+\sum_{k=1}^n kP(X=k)\\
&=n(n-1)p^2+np
\end{align}

Comment: This takes for granted that the OP knows the variance of a binomial. Maybe they do... but the general phrasing of the question (admittedly unclear) seems to indicate they do not. We shall see, I guess.

Comment: I dont undersand the step in which you go from $k^2$ to $k(k-1)+k$.

Comment: @M.Mac It's simple $k^2=k(k-1)+k$. The sum for $k=0$ vanishes, so we can consider $1\leq k\leq n$.

Answer (score 1):

$ \mathbb{E}[(\frac{X}{n}-p)^2]
=\mathbb{E}[(\frac{X}{n})^2-2(\frac{X} {n}p)+p^2]
\\ =\mathbb{E}[(\frac{X}{n})^2]+(-2)\mathbb{E}[\frac{X}{n}p]+(\mathbb{E}[X])^2 \\ = \mathbb{E}[(\frac{X}{n})^2] - 2p\mathbb{E}[\frac{X}{n}]+p^2 \\= \mathbb{E}[(\frac{X}{n})^2] - 2p\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}[X]+p^2\\ $

$\mathbb{E}[(X)^2] -(\mathbb{E}[(X)])^2 = Var(X)$

$\mathbb{E}[(X)^2]= Var(X)+(\mathbb{E}[(X)])^2$

$\mathbb{E}[(X)^2] = np(1-p) + n^2p^2$

($Var(X) = np(1-p)$)

$(\mathbb{E}[(\frac{X}{n})^2] = \frac{1}{n^2}(\mathbb{E}[(X)^2)$

$ \mathbb{E}[(\frac{X}{n}-p)^2]=\frac{np(1-p)}{n^2} + \frac{n^2p^2}{n^2}- 2p\frac{np}{n}+p^2 \\= \frac{np(1-p)}{n^2} = \frac{pq}{n}$

Comment: What do you take for granted, what do you (re)prove? Provided you make this much clearer, your answer is not useful.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  I thought I gave a clean solution

Comment: @Did, the place where he misses is the variance.  That is exactly what I have illustrated

Comment: "I don't understand your comment" Too bad. Which words do you fail to understand in it? "the place where he misses is the variance" Actually, no. Note that the word "variance" is not even mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Did,I hope I made it clearer now.  The other responder has used the same variance to prove the relationship.

Comment: Interestingly, you suddenly found a way to "understand" my first comment? Anyway, the new version of your post takes for granted that the OP knows the variance of a binomial. Maybe they do... but the general phrasing of the question (admittedly unclear) seems to indicate they do not. We shall see, I guess.

Comment: I am assuming that if the person knows $(\mathbb{E}[(X)])$, I would suppose that he is exposed to variance too.

Comment: I did not suddenly understand your first comment, honestly I thought knowledge of variance is a given if the student is asked to solve this problem

Comment: Thats true, we dont know the variance but in a task we showed $\mathbb{E}[(X-np)^2] = npq$, which is the variance :).

Comment: "honestly I thought knowledge of variance is a given if the student is asked to solve this problem" Honestly it is a rather illogical assumption to make since the computation the OP is asked to perform is exactly the computation of the variance of $X/n$. Of course, one can "answer" every question "Please compute value V" by "**We know that** V is so and so hence V is so and so" but what is the use to the OP asking about V?

Comment: @M.Mac Ah, so your question is actually that you know the variance of $X$ and you are asking about the variance of $X/n$? Then this suggests radically different answers than the ones above.

Comment: @Did, I am being innocent here and I believe M.Mac is too.  I am sorry if any of my assumptions irritated you.

Comment: "Innocent"? Irrelevant. "Irritated""? Irrelevant (and rather insulting, if one thinks about it). Why change the subject?

Comment: @Did But you are correct, the definition of the variance was not given, it was a side task.